# Drag and Drop RecyclerView Which is Populated from SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

**Info:**

I have a `RecyclerView`, and I populate it with the ArrayList *dataList* inside the `ListAdapter` class. I get the data for *dataList* from the `SQLiteDatabase` table: *TABLE_USERdETAIL* in the `DbHelper` class. I'm trying to implement drag and drop re-organisation into the `RecyclerView` by using the `SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback` class; however, although I am now able to move the `RecyclerView` elements, the list doesn't re-sort or move; I'm only able to temporarily drag the list elements over each other, as shown in the image below, but it's meant to be permanently slotting the list elements into whichever position it's held:

I expect the problem to be within the `ListAdapter` class, inside the method onItemMove, but I don't know how to solve my issue.

**Question:** How do I make this drag and drop feature actually re-organise the `RecyclerView` data list?

**Update 5:** I have updated my current code for further assistance.

### ListAdapter Class

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<UserData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Listener listener;
    DbHelper dbHelper;



    public interface Listener {
        void nameToChnge(String name);
    }

    public ListAdapter(Context context, List<UserData> dataList1) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataList1;
        //this.listener= (Listener) context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @Override
    public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recylerview_one, parent, false);
        ListViewHolder viewHolder = new ListViewHolder(convertView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.tv_name.setText(dataList.get(position).name);
        holder.tv_quantity.setText(dataList.get(position).quantity);
        holder.tv_description.setText(dataList.get(position).description + " ");

        if(dataList.get(position).description.isEmpty()) {
            holder.tv_description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.relLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String s = dataList.get(position).id;
                Integer stringo = Integer.parseInt(s);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemEditActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ItemNumber", stringo);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {
        TextView tv_name, tv_quantity, tv_description;
        RelativeLayout relLayout;

        public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameDisplay);
            tv_quantity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantityDisplay);
            tv_description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionDisplay);
            relLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relLayout);
        }
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected() {
            Log.d("ListViewHolder", "item selected");
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClear() {
            Log.d("ListViewHolder", "item clear");
            for (int count = 0; count < dataList.size(); count++) {
                UserData u = dataList.get(count);
                u.setSort(count);
                dbHelper.updateUserData(u);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
        dataList.remove(position);
        //dbHelper = DbHelper.getInstance(context);
        //dbHelper.deleteRowItem(position + 1);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    //Collections.swap(dataList, fromPosition, toPosition);
    //notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);


    public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
            for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
                Collections.swap(dataList, i, i + 1);
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
                Collections.swap(dataList, i, i - 1);
            }
        }
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        return true;
    }
}
```

### SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback Class

```
public class SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {
    private final ListAdapter  mAdapter;


    public SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(ListAdapter adapter) {
        mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {return true; }

    @Override
    public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() { return false; }

    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
        int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                          RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                          RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        mAdapter.onItemMove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        mAdapter.onItemDismiss(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
        // We only want the active item to change
        if (actionState != ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE) {
            if (viewHolder instanceof ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) {
                // Let the view holder know that this item is being moved or dragged
                Log.i("ADAPTER", "----DRAGGING----");
                ItemTouchHelperViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) viewHolder;
                itemViewHolder.onItemSelected();
            }
        }

        super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState);
    }
    @Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);

        if (viewHolder instanceof ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) {
            // Tell the view holder it's time to restore the idle state
            ItemTouchHelperViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) viewHolder;
            itemViewHolder.onItemClear();
        }
    }
}
```

### DbHelper Class

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
   private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserDatabase";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static DbHelper mDbHelper;

    public static String TABLE_USERdETAIL = "userdetail";

    private static final String _ID = "_id";
    private static final String SORT_ID = "sort_id";
    private static final String NAME = "name";
    private static final String QUANTITY = "quantity";
    private static final String WEIGHT = "weight";
    private static final String WEIGHTTOTAL = "weighttotal";
    private static final String VALUE = "value";
    private static final String VALUETOTAL = "valuetotal";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";

    public static synchronized DbHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mDbHelper == null) {
            mDbHelper = new DbHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mDbHelper;
    }

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_USERDETAIL_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERdETAIL +
                "(" +
                _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " +
                SORT_ID + " INTEGER," +
                NAME + " TEXT," +
                QUANTITY + " INTEGER," +
                WEIGHT + " INTEGER," +
                WEIGHTTOTAL + " INTEGER," +
                VALUE + " INTEGER," +
                VALUETOTAL + " INTEGER," +
                DESCRIPTION + " TEXT" +
                ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_USERDETAIL_TABLE);
    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion != newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_USERdETAIL + " ADD COLUMN " + WEIGHT + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_USERdETAIL + " ADD COLUMN " + WEIGHTTOTAL + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_USERdETAIL + " ADD COLUMN " + VALUE + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_USERdETAIL + " ADD COLUMN " + VALUETOTAL + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
        }
    }

    /**
   Insert a  user detail into database
   */
    public void insertUserDetail(UserData userData) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        db.beginTransaction();

        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(SORT_ID, userData.sort_id);
            values.put(NAME, userData.name);
            values.put(QUANTITY, userData.quantity);
            values.put(WEIGHT, userData.weight);
            values.put(WEIGHTTOTAL, userData.weighttotal);
            values.put(VALUE, userData.value);
            values.put(VALUETOTAL, userData.valuetotal);
            values.put(DESCRIPTION, userData.description);


            db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_USERdETAIL, null, values);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }


    }

    public void updateUserDetail(int id, String v1, String v2, String v3, String v4, String v5, String v6, String v7){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(NAME, v1);
        values.put(QUANTITY, v2);
        values.put(DESCRIPTION, v3);
        values.put(WEIGHT, v4);
        values.put(WEIGHTTOTAL, v5);
        values.put(VALUE, v6);
        values.put(VALUETOTAL, v7);
        db.update(TABLE_USERdETAIL, values, "_id="+id, null);
    }

   /**
   fetch all data from UserTable
    */
    public List<UserData> getAllUser() {
        List<UserData> usersdetail = new ArrayList<>();

        String USER_DETAIL_SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USERdETAIL + " ORDER BY " + SORT_ID + " COLLATE NOCASE;";

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(USER_DETAIL_SELECT_QUERY, null);

        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    UserData userData = new UserData();
                    userData.id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
                    userData.sort_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(SORT_ID));
                    userData.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NAME));
                    userData.quantity = "Quantity: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(QUANTITY));
                    userData.weight = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WEIGHT));
                    userData.weighttotal = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WEIGHTTOTAL));
                    userData.value = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VALUE));
                    userData.valuetotal = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VALUETOTAL));
                    userData.description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DESCRIPTION));

                    usersdetail.add(userData);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return usersdetail;

    }

    /**
   Delete single row from UserTable
     */
    void deleteRow(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            db.beginTransaction();
            db.execSQL("delete from " + TABLE_USERdETAIL + " where name ='" + name + "'");
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    }

    void deleteRowItem(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            db.beginTransaction();
            db.execSQL("delete from " + TABLE_USERdETAIL + " where _id ='" + id + "'");
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    }

    public UserData getSingleUserDetail(String userId) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        UserData userData = null;

        //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USERdETAIL, null);

        // this is the code to order the RecyclerView by _ID:
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USERdETAIL + " WHERE " + _ID + "= ?", new String[]{userId});
        try {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                userData = new UserData();
                userData.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NAME));
                userData.quantity = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(QUANTITY));
                userData.weight = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WEIGHT));
                userData.weighttotal = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WEIGHTTOTAL));
                userData.value = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VALUE));
                userData.valuetotal = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VALUETOTAL));
                userData.description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DESCRIPTION));
            }
            cursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return userData;
    }

    public int getTotalWeight() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(WEIGHTTOTAL) FROM userdetail", null);
        if(cur.moveToFirst())
        {
            return cur.getInt(0);
        }
        cur.close();
        return getTotalWeight();
    }

    public int getTotalQuantity() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) FROM userdetail", null);
        if(cur.moveToFirst())
        {
            return cur.getInt(0);
        }
        cur.close();
        return getTotalQuantity();
    }

    public int getTotalValue() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(VALUETOTAL) FROM userdetail", null);
        if(cur.moveToFirst())
        {
            return cur.getInt(0);
        }
        cur.close();
        return getTotalValue();
    }

    public int getMaxColumnData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        final SQLiteStatement stmt = db
                .compileStatement("SELECT MAX(SORT_ID) FROM " + TABLE_USERdETAIL);

        return (int) stmt.simpleQueryForLong();
    }

    public void updateUserData(UserData userData) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(NAME, userData.getName());
        values.put(QUANTITY, userData.getQuantity());
        values.put(DESCRIPTION, userData.getDescription());
        values.put(WEIGHT, userData.getWeight());
        values.put(WEIGHTTOTAL, userData.getWeighttotal());
        values.put(VALUE, userData.getValue());
        values.put(VALUETOTAL, userData.getValuetotal());
        values.put(SORT_ID, userData.getSort());

        Log.i("DBhelper", "USER UPDATED = " + userData.getName());

        db.update(TABLE_USERdETAIL, values, _ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(userData.getId())});

    }
}
```

### UserData

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class UserData implements Serializable {
    String id, name, quantity, weight, weighttotal, value, valuetotal, description;
    int sort_id;

    public UserData() {
        super();
    }

    public void setId(String id){
        this.id= id;
    }
    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public void setSort(int sort){
        this.sort_id= sort;
    }
    public int getSort(){
        return sort_id;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name= name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description= description;
    }
    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }
    public void setQuantity(String quantity){
        this.quantity= quantity;
    }
    public String getQuantity(){
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setWeight(String weight){
        this.weight= weight;
    }
    public String getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }
    public void setWeighttotal(String weighttotal){
        this.weighttotal= weighttotal;
    }
    public String getWeighttotal(){
        return weighttotal;
    }
    public void setValue(String value){
        this.value= value;
    }
    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }
    public void setValuetotal(String valuetotal){
        this.quantity= valuetotal;
    }
    public String getValuetotal(){
        return quantity;
    }
}
```

### ItemTouchHelperViewHolder Class

```
public interface ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {
    void onItemSelected();
    void onItemClear();
}
```

### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListAdapter.Listener {


    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DbHelper dbHelper;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    private ItemTouchHelper mItemTouchHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        dbHelper = DbHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_contactlist);
        adapter = new ListAdapter(this, dbHelper.getAllUser());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback =
                new SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(adapter);
        mItemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
        mItemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.about_task:
                Intent intentChangeActivity2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentChangeActivity2);
                return true;
            case R.id.encumbrance_task:
                Intent intentChangeActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EncumbranceActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentChangeActivity);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        dbHelper = DbHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_contactlist);
        adapter = new ListAdapter(this, dbHelper.getAllUser());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

    @Override
    public void nameToChnge(String name) {
        dbHelper.deleteRow(name);

        adapter = new ListAdapter(this, dbHelper.getAllUser());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
```

}

### Error log:

```
8-26 11:20:49.443 23533-23533/name.appE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: name.app, PID: 23533
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void name.app.DbHelper.updateUserData(name.app.UserData)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at name.app.ListAdapter$ListViewHolder.onItemClear(ListAdapter.java:95)
                                                                           at name.app.SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback.clearView(SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback.java:63)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper$3.onAnimationEnd(ItemTouchHelper.java:619)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.animation.HoneycombMr1AnimatorCompatProvider$AnimatorListenerCompatWrapper.onAnimationEnd(HoneycombMr1AnimatorCompatProvider.java:115)
                                                                           at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1149)
                                                                           at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1309)
                                                                           at android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(AnimationHandler.java:146)
                                                                           at android.animation.AnimationHandler.-wrap2(AnimationHandler.java)
                                                                           at android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame(AnimationHandler.java:54)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:869)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:616)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: Hi, the question is too long, in my opinion you should simplify in order to receive more attention. On the other hand, let me know if i understand, when you d&d an item, returns to its original position? Maybe you can try implementing ItemTouchHelper in your ViewHolder class, and then in OnItemClear method store the order in your database. Hope it helps!

Comment: @noe I appreciate your point, I'll re-write the question. Yes, it just returns back to it's original position, and I'll try your suggestion - thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Tom, what do you mean with re-organize the RecyclerView data list? When you drag&drop an item it just takes up the new position and the others shift down or up. This behavior actually re-organize de list right?

Comment: @leobelizquierdo Yes, when I drag and drop an item, I would like the item to take up the new position on the list. However, my app only drags the item, before dropping it back into it's original position, it doesn't actually change the order of the list

Comment: @Tom, are you sure that `onMove` is been called? What shows your log after `onItemMove` execute?

Comment: @leobelizquierdo,  it repeatedly logs the position I'm holding the item over, starting from 0

Comment: maybe you should put more details in the log something like `Log.d(TAG, fromPosition + " - " + toPosition)`. The same inside the for: `Log.d(TAG, i + " - " + (i+1))` to see what is actually swapping.

Comment: @leobelizquierdo I used `Log.d(TAG, i + " - " + (i+1))` and it logs every 0.1 second, "_the correct position of the dragged item - _the correct position of the item it's held over_". Still can't work out to switch the two though, it the item just hovers over the list.

Comment: @Tom, the only way I get the same behavior has you do is when don't call `notifyItemMoved`, the list acts like in your example image (the neighbor items don't move when the selected pass hover them). But when I add `notifyItemMoved` everything works fine.

Comment: @leobelizquierdo I'm calling `notifyItemMoved` directly after my `Log.d(TAG, i + " - " + (i+1))`. It just hovers over it. Looking at the logs, when I drag past 2 items, it starts logging both item positions that it's passed.

Comment: notifyItemMoved(i, i-1); is what I'm calling, I didn't edit it time

Comment: `notifyItemMoved(i, i-1);` isn't what is in your code sample! Do you try what I mentioned in my answer? Try this: `@Override
public void onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    Collections.swap(mItems, fromPosition, toPosition);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
}`

Comment: @leobelizquierdo sorry, I'm using your answer now, the `Override` is redlined "_Method does not override method from its superclass_". Without the `Override` it is hovering like I started.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that catching your problem but what i noticed (hope this helps):
in your `onItemMove` you are refactoring `dataList` by swapping items but adapter notifies only about general change.

guess the simplest way to move the item (and save animation) is to remove it and add again:

```
UserData item = dataList.remove(fromPosition);
dataList.add(i, toPossition);
notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
```

Comment: you don't need to remove the item and add it again, just `swap` the two involved items and notify the adapter with `notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)`.

Comment: I tried implementing your answer, but `remove(fromPosition)` is causing and error that starts as _java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1_

Comment: is `dataList` contains 2 entries at start? how many times `onItemMove` calls?

Comment: @user5599807 `onItemMove` is called every time the item has been dragged move to a different position. if `dataList` has 2 entries it's called one time.

Comment: I tried implementing your answer, but there is no change in the drag&drop behaviour,

Answer (score 3):

EDITED: Look at the complete example [here](https://github.com/noecivitillo/SortRecyclerView)

I tested your code and your `OnItemMove` method is working as expected.
Probably, you have problems to store the order in your database?

Here you have an example:

1- Create `ItemTouchHelperViewHolder` interface:

```
public interface ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {
    void onItemSelected();
    void onItemClear();
}
```

Now implement it in your `ViewHolder` class.

2- Go to `SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback` class and add this two methods:

```
@Override
    public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
        if (actionState != ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE) {
            if (viewHolder instanceof ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) {
                ItemTouchHelperViewHolder itemViewHolder = 
                (ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) viewHolder;
                itemViewHolder.onItemSelected();
            }
        }
        super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState);
    }
@Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);

        if (viewHolder instanceof ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) {
            // Tell the view holder it's time to restore the idle state
            ItemTouchHelperViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) viewHolder;
            itemViewHolder.onItemClear();
        }
    }
```

3- In `OnItemClear` (ViewHolder class) store the new order:

```
 @Override
        public void onItemClear() {
            for (int count = 0; count < dataList.size(); count++) {
                UserData u = dataList.get(count);
                u.setOrder(count);
                mDbHelper.updateOrder(u);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: Do I put  the code samples 1 and 3 in `ListAdapter` class?

Comment: In your class named ListViewHolder

Comment: I'm struggling to understand, sorry. I can't see how code sample 1 can be put in `ListViewHolder`, it says _"inner classes cannot have static declarations"_, but I can put it in the rest of the `ListAdapter` class. I also don't know where to put code sample 3, it says the `Override` isn't over-riding it's superclass.

Comment: @TomJames Sir, Have you tried my suggestion? my code works fine and it saves all the positions after performing drag and drop on a textview in recycler view and manages postions of items as you asked for.

Comment: @Noe I'm sorry, your code is still too unclear for me. I've reproduced your `ListAdapter` class sample identically, however the `Override`'s are still not apparently over-riding their superclass for `onItemSelected` and `onItemClear`; these 2 methods are also greyed out, as if they're not in use, and I additionally, cannot resolve `setOrder` or `adapter`.

Comment: @Noe Additionally, I don't know where `onItemSelected` in the `ViewHolder` class came from, because it wasn't in your original example code

Comment: These two methods `OnItemSelected` and `OnItemClear`, came from the step 1. Have you  created the interface `ItemTouchHelperViewHolder`?

Comment: Sorry, `setOrder` is like your `setSort` method

Comment: @Noe Okay, I've put both parts of step 2 in `SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback`; I've also put step 1 in `SimpleItemTouchHelperCallack` because it was red-lining everywhere else - now `SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback` appears to fine (no red-lines). Inside class `ListViewHolder` I've put `onItemSelected` and `onItemClear` just like you wrote in your example `ListAdapter` class. However, these two `onItem` methods are never used (greyed out); the `Overrides` apparently don't over-ride their superclass; and I still don't really understand your explanation of what `setOrder` and `updateOrder` do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136027/discussion-between-noe-and-tom-james).

Comment: Hi noe, I've recently taken another go with your answer and have a much clearer understanding of it. I've implemented your code exactly as provided in your git however the drag&drop function still doesn't swap the items, only hovers above them. I'm interested if you have anymore advice on the situation, perhaps we could open another chat?

Comment: Hey! Ok @TomJames

Comment: I've updated my question with the relevant classes. Since we last talked I had increased functionality of the app, so there are a few extra columns in the SQL Db, but the code is largely the same as before. The only difference I am aware I have to your originally provided Git is my `MainActivity` and `ListAdapter `classes are separate, whereas your Git has them together. Any thoughts? I really am stumped.

Comment: I've read your code quickly and all seems fine, the first thing that you can do is log the code, are you checking if the item's order is being updated in your db?

Comment: Well, the logs show the item is recognised as "--dragging--" and "been selected". Nothing then logs until I release the item and then it logs "item clear", it then immediately crashes due to `updateUserData` (error log updated in question). Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think my item list is populated in order of "sort_id", would it be best if we swapped each item's "sort id" values as they dragged ?

Comment: You can try, but i think it's better to sort the items after they are cleared, this way you ensure of updating the correct positions. Anyway you have a null exception, so there isn't an item to update, the reference got lost some where. You need to continue logging, check that all your items are being added when you query getAllUsers() after onItemSelected see which item is selected from your data list, the same in OnItemMove

Comment: Logging `u` (userdata) results such as `name.app.UserData@4a6db7`, so I should be getting values through to my dbHelper. I've noticed my count value is always 0 for each item, should that be the case?

Comment: Sorry, I figured the count bit out, it should be increasing but doesn't because the `if` statement can't complete

Comment: could you take this conversation to chat?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about getting your problem. But I have implemented the same using the given code. This code doesn't use SQLite but it does perform drag and drop in recycler view with some textviews. You can have a look at my code:

MovieTouchHelper.java

```
public class MovieTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
private MovieAdapter mMovieAdapter;

public MovieTouchHelper(MovieAdapter movieAdapter){
    super(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT);
    this.mMovieAdapter = movieAdapter;
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    mMovieAdapter.swap(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    mMovieAdapter.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
}
}
```

MovieAdapter.java

```
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Movie> mMovies;

public MovieAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> movies){
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mMovies = movies;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item_movie, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindMovie(mMovies.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMovies.size();
}

public void remove(int position) {
    mMovies.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public void swap(int firstPosition, int secondPosition){
    Collections.swap(mMovies, firstPosition, secondPosition);
    notifyItemMoved(firstPosition, secondPosition);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public final TextView movieNameTextView;

    public ViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        movieNameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_name);
    }

    public void bindMovie(Movie movie){
        this.movieNameTextView.setText(movie.getName());
    }
}
}
```

You can edit the code according to your need.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I've tried your answer, however the problem remains. I believe this is due to my `ArrayList` coming from an SQL - which has it's own order and isn't allowing the change.

Answer (score 1):

In `onItemMove` you don't need to make all the `swap` because the method will be called every time the selected item change its position with the item next to it. So every iteration in the `for` will be taking care on each call to the method.

> you should move the item from the old position (dragged.getAdapterPosition()) to new position (target.getAdapterPosition()) in your adapter and also call RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyItemMoved(int, int).

Your `onItemMove` should look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    Collections.swap(mItems, fromPosition, toPosition);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question to include the class that handles my item movements, does this change your answer of suggesting I use a `setOnLongClickListener`?

Comment: @Tom, the class `SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback ` was already in your previous post. Sorry, By default, ItemTouchHelper starts a drag when a View is long pressed, also you have `isLongPressDragEnabled` set to true anyway, so you don't have to set `setOnLongClickListener`